# NodeJS verify and multiple inserts in loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a problem with verifying and inserting multiple entries into my database.
The NodeJS query is within a for-loop but the query method is executed asynchronously. Not all entries in the parameter "snapshot" are inserted into the database. How can I solve this problem?

Here I have designed a flowchart to show you my logic.
[image]

I'm very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
function setAddListener(userId, snapshot) {

  //var item = snapshot.val();

  //var key = Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
  //var size = Object.keys(snapshot.val()).length;

  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(snapshot.val()).length; i++) {
    var item = Object.values(snapshot.val())[i];
    //console.log(item);
    console.log(item.shoppingListName);
    console.log(item.userId);
    console.log(item.shoppingListsKey);
    console.log(item.shoppingListKey);

    console.log("QUERY: " + "SELECT * FROM bc_shopping_list WHERE shopping_list_id = '" + item.shoppingListKey + "'");

    databasemysql.query("SELECT * FROM bc_shopping_list WHERE shopping_list_id = '" + item.shoppingListKey + "'").then(rows => {
      //console.log(results.length);
      if (error) throw error;

      if (results.length == 1) {
        console.log("Shopping-List exists :" + item.shoppingListName);
      } else {
        console.log("Not exits");

        //console.log("INSERT INTO `bc_shopping_list`(`shopping_list_id`, `user_id_fk`, `article_user_id_fk`, `shopping_list_picture_id`, `article_search`, `shopping_list_name`, `shopping_list_quantity`, `unit_id_fk`, `shopping_list_durability`, `shopping_list_bought`, `place_id_fk`, `firebase_id`) VALUES ('" + item.shoppingListKey + "', '" + item.userId + "', " + item.articleId + ", '', NULL,'" + item.shoppingListName + "', " + item.shoppingListQuantity + ", " + item.unitId+1 + ", '" + item.shoppingListDurability + "', " + item.shoppingListBought + ", " + item.placeId + ", '" + item.shoppingListsKey);

        //connection.query("INSERT INTO `bc_shopping_list`(`shopping_lists_name`, `user_id_fk`, `shopping_lists_bought`, `firebase_id`) VALUES ('" + dataSnapshot.val().shoppingListsName + "','" + dataSnapshot.val().userId + "', " + dataSnapshot.val().shoppingListsBought + ", '" +  postId2 + "')", function (error, results, fields) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        //console.log("INSERT INTO `bc_shopping_list`(`shopping_list_id`, `user_id_fk`, `article_user_id_fk`, `shopping_list_picture_id`, `article_search`, `shopping_list_name`, `shopping_list_quantity`, `unit_id_fk`, `shopping_list_durability`, `shopping_list_bought`, `place_id_fk`, `firebase_id`) VALUES ('" + item.shoppingListKey + "', '" + item.userId + "', " + item.articleId + ", '', NULL,'" + item.shoppingListName + "', " + item.shoppingListQuantity + ", " + item.unitId+1 + ", '" + item.shoppingListDurability + "', " + item.shoppingListBought + ", " + item.placeId + ", '" + item.shoppingListsKey + "')");
        connection.query("INSERT INTO `bc_shopping_list`(`shopping_list_id`, `user_id_fk`, `article_user_id_fk`, `shopping_list_picture_id`, `article_search`, `shopping_list_name`, `shopping_list_quantity`, `unit_id_fk`, `shopping_list_durability`, `shopping_list_bought`, `place_id_fk`, `firebase_id`) VALUES ('" + item.shoppingListKey + "', '" + item.userId + "', " + item.articleId + ", '', NULL,'" + item.shoppingListName + "', " + item.shoppingListQuantity + ", " + item.unitId + 1 + ", '" + item.shoppingListDurability + "', " + item.shoppingListBought + ", " + item.placeId + ", '" + item.shoppingListsKey + "')", function(error, results, fields) {
          console.log("Shopping-Lists Added :" + item.shoppingListName);
          //console.log("INSERT INTO `bc_shopping_list`(`shopping_list_id`, `user_id_fk`, `article_user_id_fk`, `shopping_list_picture_id`, `article_search`, `shopping_list_name`, `shopping_list_quantity`, `unit_id_fk`, `shopping_list_durability`, `shopping_list_bought`, `place_id_fk`, `firebase_id`) VALUES ('" + item.shoppingListKey + "', '" + item.userId + "', " + item.articleId + ", '', NULL,'" + item.shoppingListName + "', " + item.shoppingListQuantity + ", " + item.unitId+1 + ", '" + item.shoppingListDurability + "', " + item.shoppingListBought + ", " + item.placeId + ", '" + item.shoppingListsKey + "')");
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Be sure to use *prepared statements with placeholder values* to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). This is necessary to ensure any values are properly escaped and won't cause problems. Most drivers have this capability, and those like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) make it easy so there's really no excuse to not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines.

```js
function setAddListener(userId, snapshot) {
  const keys = Object.keys(snapshot.val());

  const results = keys.map((item) => {
    return databasemysql.query("SELECT * FROM bc_shopping_list WHERE shopping_list_id = '" + item.shoppingListKey + "'")
  });

  Promise.all(results).then((data) => {
    // data is an array of resolved queries.
    // do your operations here
  });
}
```

Comment: And then what ?

Comment: Thank you very much. It goes in the right direction. But how can i access in the data parameter if the query has a result ? What is the property ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. Please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.
You wrote that the "data" parameter contains an array
of resolved queries. How can I access if a query contains a row ?
Because if the query returns a row I know that
this row exists in the database.
If not I can write my insert statement.

Comment: In that case, there have to be a command like findOrCreate. Usually ORMs have that like Sequelize. You should not create queries like that. Please read more about SQL injections. Your code reminds me of Firebase and I am assuming you are using Firebase, please check their docs for findOrCreate or something along those lines. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes it is firebase, i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `for loop` use `map`. inside of map return each query without `.then`. Because `map` returns a new array you will have an array of promises. Then take that array and pass it to `Promise.all([yourArray])`. In that case you will `resolve` all of your queries. Please stop using `var` in general. Never use it in `for loop`. It is discouraged my Google Style Guides. https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-local-variable-declarations